# ¿Por qué me aparece el error "Al tipo "Model<XXXX, {}, {}, {}>" le faltan las propiedades siguientes del tipo "XXXXX" y cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb

Ahora estoy de lleno en una aplicación NodeJS, y tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy desarrollando el siguiente modelo, `Suggestion`:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * User model
 * @module models/Suggestion
 */

import { Model, model,Schema, ObjectId } from 'mongoose';
import db = require('../lib/utils/db');
const dbUtils = require("../lib/utils/db");


/*  Model Interfaces    */


export interface ISuggestion extends IAddSuggestion{
    userId : String;
    subject : String;
    message: String;
    sendDate : Date;


};

export interface IAddSuggestion{
    subject : String;
    message: String;
};

export interface ISuggestionMongoModel extends ISuggestion, Model<ISuggestion>{

  _id: ObjectId;
  addSuggestion(newSuggestion: ISuggestion): Promise<ISuggestionMongoModel>;

};



/*  DB Model    */
const schema = new Schema<ISuggestionMongoModel>({
    userId : String,
    subject : String,
    message: String,
    sendDate : Date,

  });


  //let Suggestion = model<ISuggestionMongoModel>('Suggestion', schema);

  /**
 * Add new Suggestion
 * @method new
 * @param {ISuggestion} newSuggestion The record to insert in the database
 * @return {Promise<ISuggestion>}
 */
schema.statics.addSuggestion = function (newSuggestion: ISuggestion): Promise<ISuggestionMongoModel> {
  try {
    let row = dbUtils.insertRow(Suggestion, newSuggestion);
    return row;
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};


const Suggestion: ISuggestionMongoModel = model<ISuggestion, ISuggestionMongoModel>("Suggestion", schema);


  export {Suggestion};
```

Y no puedo utilizar los atributos o métodos en otros archivos, ya que me aparece el siguiente error:

> Al tipo "Model<ISuggestion, {}, {}, {}>" le faltan las propiedades
> siguientes del tipo "ISuggestionMongoModel": _id, addSuggestion,
> userId, subject y 2 más.ts(2740) const Suggestion:
> ISuggestionMongoModel

¿Por qué me aparece este error?

Answer (score 0):

Pues la respuesta era sencilla. Se trataba solamente de eliminar el tipo de schema:

```
/*  DB Model    */
const schema = new Schema({
    userId : String,
    subject : String,
    message: String,
    sendDate : Date,

  });
```

En lugar de:

```
/*  DB Model    */
const schema = new Schema<ISuggestionMongoModel>({
    userId : String,
    subject : String,
    message: String,
    sendDate : Date,

  });
```